# Stream very large table via spring-data-jdbc Resultset.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY

Tags: java, jdbc, spring-data, persistence, spring-data-jdbc

Hi I would like to stream a very large table spring-data-jdbc. For this purpose 
I have set my connection to READ_ONLY I have declared in my repository a method that looks in the following way:

```
PackageRepository extends Repository<Package,String> {

Stream<Package> findAll();

}
```

My expectation here would be that the resultset would be of type FORWARD_ONLY and this method will not block indefinatly untill all results are recieved from the database.

Here I would make a comparison with Spring Data JPA where the Stream methods are not blocking and the content of the database is fetched in portions depending on the fetch size.

Have I missed some configuration ? How can I achieve this behaviour with spring-data-jdbc ?

UPDATE: I will put the question in a different form. How can I achieve with spring-data-jdbs the equivalent of:

```
template.query(new PreparedStatementCreator() {

            @Override
            public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection con) throws SQLException {
                PreparedStatement statement =  con.prepareStatement("select * from MYTABLE with UR",ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
                statement.setFetchSize(150000);
                return statement;
            }
        }, new RowCallbackHandler() {

            @Override
            public void processRow(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {

                // do my processing here
            }
        });
```

Comment: Judging from the source code it seems as cursors are not supported yet. I noticed that for findAll method in the MyBatisDataAccessStrategy  it has been used sqlSession().selectList() shoudn't be used a cursor here ?  SqlSession.selectCursor​  ?

Comment: I think I got it, basicly I need to define my own DefaultDataAccessStrategy. If I have got it right.

Comment: You are right, this isn't supported yet, but I like the idea. And I see you already created a ticket: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJDBC-356 Thanks for that.

Comment: I started working on a solution for this issue and added some comments on the Jira issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding the`setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE)` before querying, the `queryForStream` indeed gives us a stream which load records one by one rather than eagerly load all records into memroy in one shot.

```
namedTemplate.getJdbcTemplate().setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
Stream<LargeEntity> entities = namedTemplate.queryForStream(sql, params, rowMapper);
```

dependencies:

```
spring framework 5.3+
mysql-connector-java 8.0.x (or mariadb-java-client 2.7.x)
```